# Gatsby JS files expiry headers

Tags: gatsby

I am trying to get my head around expiry headers for JS files generated by Gatsby JS. There is an article about caching on the official website: https://www.gatsbyjs.org/docs/caching/. Author suggests to use `cache-control: public, max-age=0, must-revalidate` header for JS files.

I would like to cache all JS resources. What are possible implications of usage of `cache-control: max-age=31536000, public`? Currently, I am using `1.9.192` version and JS file hashes are anyway different on each build.

By the way, there is a `gatsby-plugin-offline` which allows to cache JS resources using service worker. What could a reason why I should not use long term browser cache then?

Answer (score 2):

The JS file names *often* change but webpack 1's architecture doesn't allow us to guarantee is like later versions do. `gatsby-plugin-offline` can create problems because of this.

Luckily Gatsby v2 is close to coming and we'll all be able to forget about this mess :-)